# Using pipeline with preprocessing steps with GridsearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, grid-search

I am using a imblearn's pipeline as an estimator and gridsearchcv for hyperparameter tuning as seen below:

```
pipeline = imbpipeline(steps = [['scaler', MinMaxScaler()],
                                ['smote', SMOTE(random_state=11)],                               
                                ['classifier',LogisticRegression() ]])

search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, classifier_params, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv_inner, refit=True)

search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here train set is used for hyperparameter tuning, splitted to subtrain and validation in each fold.
My problem is this:
For the  minmaxscaler and the logistic regression part i would like fit_transform applied on each subtrain set and just transform to be applied on each corresponding validation set, which i think is what is done here.
However, for SMOTE i would like  fit_transform applied to each subtrain set but leave each corresponding validation set untouched but i am not sure if this is the case here.
Does someone know more about this?
If this is not the case is there an example where gridsearch cv is coded on a lower level?(maybe the CV part is implemented 'by hand')

Answer (score 1):

From the imblearn pipeline [documentation](https://imbalanced-learn.org/dev/references/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

> The samplers are only applied during fit.

Comment: That means that within each CV step the validation fold is left unchanged,right?

Comment: unchanged by the resampler, yes (and `transform`ed by transformers)